# how to disable checkbox on button clcik in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I'm developing a web application in classic ASP and got stuck in a conman task. I want to hide a checkbox on page load and when I click on a button, if condition matched. so I had written the following code to disable checkbox when the button is clicked but it's not working can someone help me?

```
function ReloadModel()
{
    document.getElementById("chkCategory5").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("frmProgramMaster").action = "dsp_EditProgramMaster.asp?ID=<%= txtID %>";
    document.frmProgramMaster.submit();
}
```

Comment: you want to hide checkbox using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide checkbox using javascript then:

instead of this

```
document.getElementById("chkCategory5").disabled = true;
```

use this:

```
document.getElementById("chkCategory5").style.display = 'none';
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/68ryasga/

Answer (score 0):

If you need disable de checkbox, you could use this function:

```
function disable(idCheckbox) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(idCheckbox);
  checkbox.setAttribute("disabled", "false");
}
```

Comment: i would like to hide check box when button click and form load based on condition in classic asp script function